# Background images on mobile devices not displayed correctly

Tags: html, css, image

I'm making the layout in sections. Image/Text/Image/Text... and the images have this CSS :

```
#change {
background-image: url("../images/main.png");
background-attachment: fixed;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

HTML

```
<section id="change"
data-type="background"
data-speed="5"
data-selection="0" 
style="height: 630px;
background-position: 50% 16px">
```

On a PC the images are displayed nicely. But on a mobile device the images are not corresponding to the CSS but displaying in full-res. Hence I see only a corner of a 5000x3500px image. I'm using Bootstrap in this project and Safari (iPhone 4s).

It's currently on a free host so excuse me for adds. (Also I didn't work yet on minimizing load time for the images, so sorry for that too.)

The website:
http://viso.lv/imigracija/

UPDATE: It seems that only iPhones have a problem of displaying the images. Because several people with other phones have the images just right. What can I do about that? I tried 3 different browsers. Nothing changed.

Comment: BTW, Serversfree.com is the best free host I've found, and one of the only ones I've found that's ad-free.  I suggest you check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you're asking.  For me (Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini) the images look fine.  There's some lag when scrolling, but that's perfectly natural for a mobile browser (Firefox Mobile) handling large images with CSS.

Unless there's another issue other than positioning, which is the fault of a browser without strong CSS skills, then there isn't much you can do, sorry.

Comment: You mean that the images are displayed as on a PC? Well, I'm using iPhone 4s and the images are displayed in their full resolution. Hence I see only a corner of a 5000px x 3500px image.

Comment: My phone loads the image at full-res, centered, and within its confines.  I don't have an iPhone 4s to verify, but using Chrome emulation (which I'll admit isn't always accurate) I see the image centered and in full height.  In other words, can't reproduce bug.  Have you tried another browser on your phone?

Comment: Hmm, that's encouraging but still that can be an issue for others, too, as Safari (which I'm using) is quit common for iPhones. Haven't tried other browsers yet. Yes, Chrome DevTools shows the layout just fine